# Prove if a set of first order logic formulas is satisfiable

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, quantifiers

How can I prove if a set of first order logic formulas is satisfiable or not?

For example, if I have the following set:

$\{∃x∀y¬R(y,x),∀yR(y,y)\}$

Comment: In this case, just use the definition of satisfiable: to show that it is satisfiable, show that there is a model with an interpretation of $R$ in which the sentences hold; and to show that it is not satisfiable, show that in no model with an interpretation of $R$, the sentences both hold.

Comment: So basically I just need to find a set $A$ and an interpretation of $R^A$ where the formulas are both true and that's my proof done?

Comment: Yes, *if* the set of formulas *is* satisfiable, then that is a proof. Of course, if they are not, that will not be impossible.

Comment: If I say that $A=\{1,2,3\}$ and $R^A=\{(1,1),(2,2),(3,3)\}$ the formulas are both true, correct?

Comment: No, the first one is not satisfied. To respond to your comment below, $x$ and $y$ can indeed have the same value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Hint*

For *unsatisfiability*, you can try to find a contradiction.

The first premise implies, for some $a$:

> $∀y¬R(y,a)$.

Then, instantiating both the above formula and the second premise with $a$, we get :

> > $¬R(a,a)$ and $R(a,a)$

a contradiction.

Comment: If I say that $A = \{1,2,3\}$ and $R^A = \{(1,1),(2,2),(3,3)\}$ the set is satisfiable, correct?

Comment: @JoãoSilva - No: $∃x∀y¬R(y,x)$ is not.

Comment: But if $y=1$ and $x=3$ the sentence is not true, and the same thing happens when $y=2$ and $y=3$. Question: is $∃x∀y¬R(y,x)$ the same as $∀y∃x¬R(y,x)$?

Comment: Wait, can $x$ have the same value of $y$?

Comment: @JoãoSilva - "\forall" means **for all**.

Comment: I don't understand why $∃x∀y¬R(y,x)$ is not satisfiable given the structure above. Can you give me an example where it is not true?

Comment: I understand now. Let's say that my set is $\{∃xR(x),∀x¬R(x)\}$ I can say that it isn't satisfiable because if $A = \mathbb{N}$ and $R^A = \{n \in \mathbb{N} | n is even\}$ then $∀x¬R(x)$ is not true, correct?

Comment: @JoãoSilva - Correct, but... to show that it is *unsatisfiable* you have to prove that there is **no** interpretation where it is true. Thus, it does not suffice to consider one interpretation. In the case of your comment, you have to consider that $∀x¬R(x)$ is equiv to $¬∃xR(x)$, and thus the set with the two formulas is inconsistent, i.e. unsat.

Comment: @JoãoSilva - you are welcome :-)